# Execute package in ssis causes Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ssis

I have this code

```
    var connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SSIS"].ConnectionString);
            var integrationServices = new IntegrationServices(connection);

            var package = integrationServices
                .Catalogs["SSISDB"]
                .Folders["MYFOLDER"]
                .Projects["MYPROJECT"]
                .Packages["MYPACKAGE.dtsx"];

            var executionParameters = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet>();
            var executionParameter = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet();
            executionParameter.ObjectType = 50;
            executionParameter.ParameterName = "SYNCHRONIZED";
            executionParameter.ParameterValue = 1;
            executionParameters.Add(executionParameter);

            long executionIdentifier = package.Execute(true, null, executionParameters);
```

As soon as I call package.Execute, it causes the error Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

I already adjusted the timeouts [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81928/routine-to-backup-ssas-databases-fails-with-the-xml-for-analysis-request-timed/82485#82485) but error exist.

If I remove the parameter executionParameter.ParameterName = "SYNCHRONIZED",
problem is removed. but I would like to do the call to execute synchronously.

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like there is a 30 seconds timeout on executing packages which you cannot override. You may need to overcome this limitation by executing the package asynchronously and then waiting for it to complete. See below

```
ExecutionOperation operation = ssisServer.Catalogs["SSISDB"].Executions[executionIdentifier];

while (!operation.Completed))
{
  operation.Refresh();

  // Wait before refreshing again
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

See [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7f0967af-fdeb-4040-9c57-2fe14f2291b5/timeout-after-30-seconds-when-executing-package-via-net?forum=sqlintegrationservices) for more details

Comment: Thanks,you answered two of my questions, this question and the question I was about to ask "how do I loop the execution status in .net", which is I about to ask